# how to get response(or responsebody) using restTempate.excute when another server send me "503 status"

Tags: spring, resttemplate, http-status-code-503

(This is blueprint of our service)

```
webpage <-> proxy-server <-> api-server <-> datebase
[-------- my work ---------][------- not mine -------]
```

I send request from proxy-server to api-server using "RestTemplate.exchange".

```
@Override
    public <T> ResponseEntity<T> exchange(RequestEntity<?> requestEntity, ParameterizedTypeReference<T> responseType)
            throws RestClientException {

        Assert.notNull(requestEntity, "'requestEntity' must not be null");

        Type type = responseType.getType();
        RequestCallback requestCallback = httpEntityCallback(requestEntity, type);
        ResponseExtractor<ResponseEntity<T>> responseExtractor = responseEntityExtractor(type);
        return execute(requestEntity.getUrl(), requestEntity.getMethod(), requestCallback, responseExtractor);
    }
```

And this is my question.

Api server make 503 error with ?VO.
They send me like this.

```
{
  "result": {
    "responseCode": "..."
  },
  "data": {
    "time": ...,
  }
}
```

But when this response is arrived at restTemplate, restTemplate send it to errorHandler and catch exception.

```
(in RestTemplate.java)
protected void handleResponse(URI url, HttpMethod method, ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        ResponseErrorHandler errorHandler = getErrorHandler();
        boolean hasError = errorHandler.hasError(response); // -> hasError:true!
        ...
}
```

And I can't get response outside of function.
How I get this response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to catch `HttpStatusCodeException` exception for this. And you will get http status code by calling `getStatusCode()` and the body by calling `getResponseBodyAsString()` method of the exception.

**Example:**

```
try {
    restTemplate.exchange(...);
} catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getResponseBodyAsString(), e.getStatusCode());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
Similarly I make new Exception.class and ControllerAdvice.class and catch them successfully.